# Linux: cPanel queued mail stop

Tags: linux, email, cpanel, cronjob

I got a serious mistake: I have a cronjob to send bulk email to my customers, but accidentally it worked and now some of our customers recieving the mails, I already deleted the cron job and deleted the mail function codes and deleted SMTP the Mail Account from cPanel but some of our customer still getting emails look like mails in queue, anyone know how to find queued mails and stop them? I need stop all outgoing emails from the queue...

Answer (score 0):

You can use command mailq for check your mail queue.

If you using exim mail server use command:

```
exim -bp
```

If postfix:

```
postqueue -p
```

If sendmail:

```
sendmail -bp
```

If you really have many email in queue you can empty queue by commands:
exim:

```
exim -bp | exiqgrep -i | xargs exim -Mrm
```

postfix:

```
postsuper -d deferred
```

sendmail:

```
rm -rf /var/spool/mqueue/*
```

Also do not forget to [check all dns records](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/why-is-my-outgoing-email-ending-up-in-spam-folders.html) so that your letter does not get spammed.